# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab for ubuntu R2014a and I am not able to run a code because I get the following error

`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6:version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found`

when I run:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Here you can see that I have `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` but then also I get the error!

Answer (score 8):

Actually I figured out what was wrong, as my system was GCC 5.2.1,

the file `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6`   was designed for GCC 4.4.X so `Matlab` was actually picking the wrong file. I just made a symbolic link to my system's `libstdc++.so.6` using this on terminal -

`ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` is missing the glibc version and not `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`.
Now Matlab first tries the `libstdc++.so.6` in the Matlab path and fails.

From [a post from mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255846) the following should work to start matlab with the system `libstdc++.so.6`

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" matlab
```

Comment: The link is dead, and when clicking through to the Google Groups, that's dead as well (no results found). Solution still works though.

Answer (score 0):

The link from @Thomas is [available in the WayBack machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160312054121/http://www.mathworks.com:80/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255846) but this didn't work for me as I'm missing `GLIBCXX_3.4.22` which judging by `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` is **actually** missing. I fixed this by following [these steps](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/389024-why-does-matlab-r2018a-display-erroneous-message-on-ubuntu-16-04) ([also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070900/version-glibcxx-3-4-22-not-found)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when running executables from matlab's `system()` function. The executable was dependent on a different libstdc++ than matlab had available. For both matlab R2022a and R2022b on Ubuntu 22.04, I simply linked matlab's shortcut to the system's libc++ rather than the one that ships with matlab. Perhaps this is an edge case that doesn't match the OP's from years ago, but it's one I've run into with each version of matlab and had to fix multiple times, each time leading me to this Q&A.

```bash
mike@poincare:~$ ls -l /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 May 13 15:31 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.28*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 1907456 May 13 15:31 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
mike@poincare:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 May 13 07:11 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.30
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2252096 May 13 07:11 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
mike@poincare:~$ sudo rm /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
mike@poincare:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Now, matlab loads the libstdc++.so.6 from my system rather than from its own version, and things run fine.